# Angular : Lazy load multiple Modules with the same route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

I have an app where **i want to lazy load two modules** *in the same moment* **with** *the same route path*.

**My routing module would look like this :**

```
  {
    path: 'mypath',
    loadChildren: () => HomeModule,
    canLoad: [HomeGuard]
  },

   {
     path: 'mypath',
     loadChildren: () => AdvisorModule,
     canLoad: [AdvisorGuard]
   },
```

but this lead to **load only the first one**

i cant' find anyway to do it like this for example :

```
  {
    path: 'mypath',
    loadChildren: () => HomeModule, advisor module // ??
    canLoad: [// ??]
  },
```

**I don't want also to import one of them in the other** , as like this , only one module would be lazy loaded and the other automatically

**How may it do it ??**

Comment: hello, may be you can load moduleB in the second level directly after loading moduleA, in your moduleA.routing.ts, you can have something like {path:'', loadChildren: () => moduleB, pathMatch:'full' }

Comment: Wil that be even lazy loaded? Looks like it will be bundled into main bundle to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-arrange your routes by one level and you also need to add auxiliary routes for the extra components you want to load.

This works with Angular 9 (probably with 8 too)

```
{
  path: 'home',
  component: HostingComponentWithOutlets,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'featureOne',
      loadChildren: () => import('xxxxx').then(m => m.FeatureOneModule),
      canLoad: [featureOneGuard]
    },
    {
      path: 'featureTwo',
      outlet: 'outletAux1',
      loadChildren: () => import('yyyyy').then(m => m.FeatureTwoModule),
      canLoad: [featureTwoGuard]
    },
    // you can even load more components to different outlets from the same module
    // and update redirectTo and routerLink accordingly
    //{
    //  path: 'featureThree',
    //  outlet: 'outletAux2',
    //  loadChildren: () => import('yyyyy').then(m => m.featureTwoModule),
    //  canLoad: [featureTwoGuard]
    //},
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo:
        '/absolute/path/to/home(featureOne/path-to-featureOne-component//outletAux1:featureTwo/path-to-featureTwo-component)',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    }
  ]
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Hitting the 'home' route will lazy load all required modules.

In your `HostingComponentWithOutlets` html template where you need to link to 'featureOne':

```
<a [routerLink]="featureOne/path-to-featureOne-component"
```

and if you want to go straight to the full route with the auxiliary routes from a template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['.', { outlets: { 'primary': ['featureOne', 'path-to-featureOne-component'], 'outletAux1': ['featureTwo', 'path-to-featureTwo-component'] } }]"
```

`FeatureOneModule` should define 'path-to-featureOne-component' and `FeatureTwoModule` should define 'path-to-featureTwo-component' in their equivalent route definitions.

Comment: I was trying to use your solution with minor changes, but without any sucess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69235517/angular-2-12-error-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment-lazy-load-many-modu . Did I miss something?

Comment: This was a huge help, KUDOS!

Answer (score 2):

You could rework things like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'mypath/home',
    loadChildren: () => HomeModule,
    canLoad: [HomeGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'mypath/advisor',
    loadChildren: () => AdvisorModule,
    canLoad: [AdvisorGuard]
  },
]
```

In other words move the route path to your module outside to the parent module, in this case I assume those are 'adviser' and 'home'

And then just start in the module routing with a redirect solution and/or a path like so:

Home module routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // <-- in your current solution probably 'home'
    component: HomeParentComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'childOne', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'childOne', component: HomeChildComponentOne },
    ],
  },
];
```

Advisor module routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // <-- in your current solution probably 'advisor'
    component: AdvisorParentComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'childOne', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'childOne', component: AdvisorChildComponentOne },
    ],
  },
];
```

This works nicely, you should be able to navigate to:

`'/mypath/home'` and end up inside your `HomeParentComponent` with router outlet of `HomeChildComponent` one.

`'/mypath/advisor'` and end up inside your `AdvisorParentComponent` with router outlet of `AdvisorChildComponent` one.

In case you don't want a child component inside your router outlet it is even simpler, you can just remove the child routes and redirect.

---

**Note:** *If this solution doesn't resolve your issue, then please share more details on your module routing so I can get a better picture of your desired route configuration.*

Comment: What will happen if user hit '/mypath/' ? Will it lazily load HomeModule and AdvisorModule? I guess not. OP want to load those two modules, if /mypath is hit. You may want to rewrite your solution as it may be very useful.